# How to set default notification settings in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

Is it possible to set up the default notification settings for newly created events in Google Calendar, e.g. instead of:

[image]

I would like to see something like:

[image]

Comment: See [Modify Google Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cturn-notifications-on-or-off)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For "**Classic Calendar**":

1. Go to Settings.
2. Click Calendars (tab).

[image: calendars tab]

3. Click Edit notifications (link).

[image: edit notification settings by calendar]

4. Change or remove the default notification setting in Event Notifications and All Day Event Notifications Sections as desired.

[image: default notifications for new events]

---

For Google's 2017 **New Calendar**:

1. Go to Settings.
2. Click scroll down the left sidebar to Settings for my calendars.
3. Expand the desired calendar.
4. Click Event notifications or All Day Event Notifications.
5. Change the default settings as desired.

[image: default notification settings-google calendar 2017]

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer might still work (for me it didn't, for others it did), Google may have changed the settings menu since then.

An alternative route in case the above doesn't work is the following: first, choose a calendar from the left panel, and click on the three dots to choose "Settings and sharing". Then, under "Event notifications" and "All-day event notifications" you can define your preferred default behavior.

Comment: Looks like the settings are still accessible through the method in the accepted answer, going through via the "settings and sharing" is a shortcut to get to the same place.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer still works, however thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it doesn't work for me. But I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer Feb 2021. (for Google calendar on a desktop computer or laptop)

1. Go "My calendars" in the left panel
2. Hover over the calendar you want to update and click the three dots
3. Click "Settings and sharing"
4. Scroll down to "Event notifications"
5. Add the default notification type and duration

There you go!

Make sure to do it for each calendar for which you want to receive these notifications by default.

Comment: thanks, Google interfaces become more confusing every day